# Ionic 5: change event is not working on ion-select Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have just started using this Ionic framework and using it with plain JS. I an having an issue that when I select something on the select box my JS function is not triggered and not sure why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
<script>
    function changeDate() {
        alert('change date');
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<ion-app>
    <ion-tabs>

        <ion-tab tab="view">
            <ion-item color="dark">
                <ion-label class="white-text">Date Range</ion-label>
                <ion-select ionChange="changeDate()" id="airportsDateChanger" value="all">
                    <ion-select-option value="all">All</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="sevendays">Last 7 Days</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="lastthirty">Last 30 Days</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="lastninety">Last 90 Days</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="pastyear">Past Year</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="custom">custom</ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
</ion-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you add script tag after closing html tag?

Comment: @Danial just how it was from some legacy code. I am refactoring

Comment: So it's never call

Comment: @Danial it does in the old code base. Either way  there or in he head,  my intended question still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an event listener in your script tag to listen for changes on `ion-select`.

```
<script>
  function changeDate() {
    alert('change date');
  }
  document.getElementById('airportsDateChanger').addEventListener('ionChange', changeDate);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the ionChange event between **()** like (ionChange)

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="changeDate()" id="airportsDateChanger" value="all">
   ...
</ion-select>
```